# I want to check whether name contains any special character or number in Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby, selenium-webdriver

This is code -

```
def username_chk(str)
     if str.length <=20         
        if str=~/^[a-zA-Z\\s]+$/
        puts "Invalid User name"
        else
        puts str
       end  
     else puts"User name can contain Max 20 character"
     end
  end   
      username_chk("Mark ju09")
```

it's not working. I also tried:

```
str=~/[a-zA-Z]+\\.?/
```

str=~/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/ this expression working fine in java using Pattern

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote Ruby, but your code has `\\s`. Since this is a regex literal, shouldn't it be `/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/` — a single back slash before the s `\s`

Comment: Try `/[^a-zA-Z\s]/`. As noted by @GregBurghardt, you don't want a double backslash. Also, `^` outside the brackets and in first position anchors the regex to the beginning of a line. Inside the bracket it negates the set. No need for `+` or `$`, it's sufficient to find one element which is not a valid character or space. See https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/regexp_rdoc.html#label-Special+Characters for more details.

Comment: You should avoid use of the term "special character" as it is not defined in Ruby. Instead just ask how to determine if a string contains any character other than a letter (uppercase or lowercase) or a whitespace.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "special character"?

Comment: "it's not working" is not a precise enough problem description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: [ascii_only?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/String.html#method-i-ascii_only-3F)

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need to double-escape characters in a ruby regex. `\s` means "whitespace character"; `\\s` means "a backslash, then an `s`" (and `[\\s]` means a backslash *or* an `s`).
2. `=~` is a "match" operator. `str=~/^[a-zA-Z\\s]+$/` is checking for what the string *does* match, not for what it *doesn't* match.

In conclusion, there are several ways you could have written this, but here are a few:

```
# pick one of the `if` statements below...
if str =~ /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/
if str =~ /^[a-z\s]+$/i
  puts str # (valid user name)
end

# Or, pick one of these:
# (Note that !~ means "doesn't match"; the opposite of =~)
if str !~ /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/
if str !~ /^[a-z\s]+$/i
if str =~ /[^a-zA-Z\s]/
if str =~ /[^a-z\s]/i
  puts "Invalid User name"
end
```

See the docs: [Here](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Regexp.html#method-i-3D%7E) and [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-21%7E)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below regex to verify if string have at lease one special character or at least one number.

str.match?(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]|\d/)

Answer (score -1):

In the regular expression, there's no need to escape the backslash (). So, /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/ becomes /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/.
Also the order of the "Invalid User name" and puts str lines to display the username when it's valid.

```
def username_chk(str)
 if str.length <= 20
  if str =~ /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/
   puts str
  else
   puts "Invalid User name"
  end
 else
  puts "User name can contain Max 20 characters"
 end 
end

username_chk("Mark ju09")
```